# Extracting key/value pairs from JSON file

Tags: python, vb.net, uipath

I am trying to convert Python code to extract key/value pairs from JSON output (originating from Microsoft Form Recognizer) and cannot recreate the loop within VB.NET (UiPath).

So far I created a nested for-each loop in UiPath to loop through each key/value pair within each page.

```
import json

    response_file = "response.json"
    # Specify the list of keys to be reported.
    keys = set(["Number","Opened"])
    with open(response_file, mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        # Loop over all pages in the document.
        for page in data["pages"]:
            # Loop over all key/value pairs in the page.
            for kvp in page["keyValuePairs"]:
                key_txt = " ".join([x["text"] for x in kvp["key"]])
                # Report only the pre-specified subset of keys.
                if key_txt in keys:
                    print("key: %s" % key_txt)
                    vals = [x["text"] for x in kvp["value"]]
                    print("value: %s" % " ".join(vals))
```

The JSON example I am using:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "pages": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "height": 792,
      "width": 612,
      "clusterId": 0,
      "keyValuePairs": [
        {
          "key": [
            {
              "text": "Number",
              "boundingBox": [
                71.6,
                704.6,
                109.0,
                704.6,
                109.0,
                693.6,
                71.6,
                693.6
              ]
            }
          ],
          "value": [
            {
              "text": "RITM0041763",
              "boundingBox": [
                178.7,
                704.6,
                241.4,
                704.6,
                241.4,
                693.6,
                178.7,
                693.6
              ],
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "key": [
            {
              "text": "Opened",
              "boundingBox": [
                321.0,
                704.6,
                357.8,
                704.6,
                357.8,
                693.6,
                321.0,
                693.6
              ]
            }
          ],
          "value": [
            {
              "text": "09/21/2018 09:04:01 AM",
              "boundingBox": [
                428.1,
                704.6,
                536.5,
                704.6,
                536.5,
                693.6,
                428.1,
                693.6
              ],
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
```

The error in UiPath (running on VB.NET) is 'bracketed identifier is missing closing ']'.

Comment: In .Net, you can use [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (or `System.Text.Json` in .Net Core 3.0) to parse a JSON file. You can also convert the JSON to classes (quite common). Visual Studio has a Paste Special function, `Paste JSON as classes` that automates the process (not a great tool, many online services provide better conversions when the JSON is less simple).

Comment: I already have the raw JSON deserialized within UiPath, so parsing it won't be necessary - at this point I need to loop through the key/value pairs to extract the pairs that I need.

Comment: Have you posted the entire example JSON?  As from what I can see above, the last `]` closes off the last of the `values` section, but you would need a further `}` and `]` to completely close off the `pages` data?